# Automatic Git merge : one branch to another

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a requirement as whenever I push my changes to my git branch, it has to automatically merge my commit to another common git branch. Is there a way or a tool to automate this?

Comment: It's not possible with multiple developers, since, no body is there to resolve conflicts.

Comment: I understand the case of conflicts. I just want to automate if its a clean merge.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box, but you might be able to build something like this with [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

But as Kugathasan Abimaran noted, how would you solve any merge conflicts? The only way this could work out is when the "other common git branch" is always only merged from the same branch and never modified in any other way. But then why would you need it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can see https://gist.github.com/jijita/363ffcfa467979343ec3. It shows how to automate git merge